# How to query an object through its foreignkey? django

Tags: django

This is my model, which has a `foreignkey` of `User` model.

```
class StudentGrade(models.Model):
    PERIOD_CHOICES = [
        (1, 'First Grading'),
        (2, 'Second Grading'),
        (3, 'Third Grading'),
        (4, 'Fourth Grading'),
        (5, 'First Semester'),
        (6, 'Second Semester')
    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to=Q(is_student=True))
    period = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PERIOD_CHOICES)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True,)
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

and in my views.py I need to get the specific object of `StudentGrade` through its `User`.

here is my views.py :

```
def StudentGrade(request, id):
    student = StudentGrade.objects.get(user__user_id=id)
    context = {
        'student': student,
    }
    return render(request, 'student_dashboard/student_grade.html', context)
```

with these codes i am getting an error :

> AttributeError at /student/grade/4/ 'function' object has no
>   attribute 'objects'

UPDATE: 
I'm done change the view name different name from my model name. However, after doing so I got another error:

> DoesNotExist at /student/grade/3/
>   StudentGrade matching query does not exist.

Comment: you need to change your function name, your model and function name are same, thats why you are getting `'function' object has no attribute 'objects'` and change `user__user_id=id` to `user_id=id`

Comment: cannot same model class name  and views function name changes ```views.py``` function name

Comment: OK, im done changing the view name. However, after doing so I got another error : "DoesNotExist at /student/grade/3/ StudentGrade matching query does not exist."

Comment: It's okay now I just need to use the get_object_or_404 to catch the new error. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def student_grade(request, id):
    student = StudentGrade.objects.filter(user__user_id=id)
    context = {
        'student': student,
    }
    return render(request, 'student_dashboard/student_grade.html', context)
```

try this way and see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your query a bit

```
student = StudentGrade.objects.filter(user__PRIMARY_KEY_OF_USER_TABLE=id)
```